# BFD support for OSPF vyatta 6.2?

Tags: routing, router, ospf, vyatta, bfd

Is it possible to get support for BFD for OSPF on vyatta 6.2?

I cannot find any information about it on the internet. The only thing I've seen is that the support is available on Brocade Vyatta 5400 vRouter.

Does anyone know?

Comment: I see nothing about it in the change logs. I don't think BFD was included until after Brocade bought Vyatta (after 6.2), and other vendors have recently included BFD support, too.